# Using a pipe (or) in sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed, makefile

From a variable `$(JS_SOURCES)` containing something like

```
"    thing.js myapp.mod1.js otherthing.js myapp.mod1.submod.js myapp.othermodule.js   "
```

`make` writes a file containing `mod1,othermodule`.

It works with this code:

```
./build/modules.txt: $(JS_SOURCES)
    @echo "$(JS_SOURCES)" | sed -r -e 's/\s\S*myapp\.(\w+)\.js\b/ \1/g' -e 's/\S*\.\S*//g' -e 's/^\s+//' -e 's/\s+$$//' -e 's/\b\s+\b/,/g' > $@
```

And my question is Why can't I replace the 3 expressions

```
-e 's/\S*\.\S*//g' -e 's/^\s+//' -e 's/\s+$$//'
```

with one using pipes

```
-e 's/\S*\.\S*|^\s+|\s+$$//g'
```

?

The shorter sed command doesn't trim the string (the purpose of two of the expressions).

Why doesn't it work ? How to fix that (without resorting to several expressions of course) ?

OS is Ubuntu 14.10. I'm not interested in using alternative tools but in *how* to use the pipe in a regular expression with sed called from a makefile.

Comment: It works for me using GNU Make 3.81 (Ubuntu 14.04)… Which version of make are you using?

Comment: @Arkanosis `GNU Make 4.0`. Are you sure the resulting string is correctly trimmed (which is the purpose of the parts after the first pipe) ?

Comment: When I change the order of the parts, the two parts doing the trimming are always the ones being ignored. So this is probably not just about the pipe.

Comment: No, you're right, it's not trimed, indeed. But it's not in the shell either…

Comment: @Arkanosis You're right. I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arkanosis is correct: the combination is wrong and it's wrong in the shell too.  It doesn't have anything to do with make:

```
echo "    thing.js myapp.mod1.js otherthing.js myapp.mod1.submod.js myapp.othermodule.js   " \
    | sed -r -e 's/\s\S*myapp\.(\w+)\.js\b/ \1/g' \
             -e 's/\S*\.\S*//g' -e 's/^\s+//' -e 's/\s+$//' -e 's/\b\s+\b/,/g' \
          > /tmp/x.out \
    && echo "|$(cat /tmp/x.out)|"
```

shows:

```
|mod1,othermodule|
```

Now use the all-in-one method:

```
echo "    thing.js myapp.mod1.js otherthing.js myapp.mod1.submod.js myapp.othermodule.js   " \
    | sed -r -e 's/\s\S*myapp\.(\w+)\.js\b/ \1/g' \
             -e 's/\S*\.\S*|^\s+|\s+$//g' -e 's/\b\s+\b/,/g' \
          > /tmp/x.out \
    && echo "|$(cat /tmp/x.out)|"
```

and you get:

```
| mod1,othermodule|
```

You must be doing something in your shell command that's tricking you into thinking it works.

The reason it doesn't work is that in the original version, each expression in the `-e` is applied one after the other to the string, so all take effect.

In the new version, with all three conditions condensed into a single expression, it is applied only one time and only *one* of the three alternatives will be chosen (that's what the pipe symbol means in a regex).

Comment: *"only one of the three alternatives will be chosen"*. Unless I'm missing something (else), it shouldn't matter as I'm using the ̀g` flag ?

Comment: The `g` flag won't allow the pattern to re-match already-matched content.  Once some amount of text is matched by one of the alternatives that text is done and sed moves on.  It doesn't keep restarting at the beginning of the text and re-applying the same substitutions to it over and over.

Comment: Yes. Upvote for hinting at a faulty regex (even if the analysis was a little lacking: of course not just one of the three alternatives is chosen, the three were chosen, the problem is that the spaces that were in the middle end being at the ends)

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I meant, for any given section of the text only one of the three alternatives are chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as demonstrated by @Arkanosis, wasn't in the use of make.

As hinted by @MadScientist, the regex was faulty.

The problem is that while the string **is** trimmed through `s/\S*\.\S*|^\s+|\s+$$//g`, spaces that weren't initially at ends of the strings (i.e. spaces between words) aren't removed by the expression and end being at the ends of the string.

Once it is clear, the solution is obvious: remove those spaces in the third case: `s/\s*\S*\.\S*\s*|^\s+|\s+$$//g`

Except this doesn't let any space left for the next substitution, so the best simple solution I have is

```
-e 's/\S*\.\S*//g' -e 's/^\s+|\s+$$//g'
```

Comment: I thought about that but tried your solution and it doesn't work (for me) because removing all the spaces means there's nothing left for the last substitution `'s/\b\s+\b/,/g'` so no comma is added; the result when I try this is `mod1othermodule` not `mod1,othermodule`.